# Substitute keyword value ONLY in subversion keyword substitution

Tags: svn

In subversion keyword substitution, we can do that

`$Author$` replace to `$Author: hkalex@gmail.com $`

However, how can I just substitution the value **ONLY**.

What I want is

`$Author$` replace to `hkalex@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using Subversion alone.  The substitution is done like that to match not only historic CVS behavior, but to make it easy and obvious to see that the inserted text was done through keyword expansion and not just inserted manually.

If you're trying to do this as part of cleaning up files for, say, public release, you'll want to build a script to perform the replacement for you.  A bit of `grep` and `sed` should do the trick.